# How to write a loop that exits after 3 even numbers are entered

Tags: c#, loops

Could someone help me creating a simple program that will let me enter numbers and will only stop if it encounters 3 even numbers in a loop?

**Expected output**

```
Enter a number: 5
Enter a number: 55
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 8
Enter a number: 33
Enter a number: 20
Enter a number: 7
```

Comment: Your output has failed

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for taking the time to share your question. Stack Overflow is not a programming nor a course service. What is your goal & difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share some code (no screenshot), images or sketches of screens, user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Answer (score 1):

> that will let me enter numbers and will only stop if it encounters 3
> even numbers in a loop?

Sure just use `int.TryParse` and the *remainder operator*

The premise is `value % 2 == 0` will be `true` when *even*

```
var evenCount = 0;
while (evenCount < 3)
{
   Console.Write("Enter a number : ");
   if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var value) && value % 2 == 0)
      evenCount += 1;
}
Console.WriteLine("game over...");
```

**Output**

```
Enter a number : 1
Enter a number : 2
Enter a number : 3
Enter a number : 4
Enter a number : 5
Enter a number : 6
game over...
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[TryParse(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__)

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion
> succeeded.

[Remainder Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-)

> The remainder operator `%` computes the remainder after dividing its
> left-hand operand by its right-hand operand.